# Create xmlns:xsi namespace and attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I want to create the following element:

```
<exercises xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
```

If I use something like this:

```
<xsl:element name="excercises">
<xsl:attribute name="xmlns:xsi" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Then it creates soemthing like this:

```
<excercises xp_0:xsi="" xmlns:xp_0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Which doesn't look like what I want...

Comment: Which XSLT parser are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xml"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xml">
        <xsl:element name="exercises">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">mySchema.xsd</xsl:attribute>
            some value
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key concern is to declare the xsi namespace in the  declaration.

I've just made up the template match on  just to test.

Comment: Since the msxsl alais isn't used it might be better if you just removed it, it would make the example clearer

Answer (score 3):

**Here is how this can be done**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!--                                   -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <exercises  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied** on any source XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced:

```
<exercises xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

**It is not necessary to use `<xsl:attribute>` in your case**, however if necessary, it can be used without any problem:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
      <xsl:value-of select="'mySchema.xsd'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

**Do note that it is a good practice to simply define the necessary namespaces at the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element** so that they can readily be (re)used everywhere they are needed. THis is especially useful, if a given namespace will be needed on more than one generated element or attribute.

**In this case it is also good to specify all such prefixes in the value of the [`exclude-result-prefixes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element) attribute** so that the namespaces will not be automatically propagated on all literal result elements.

Comment: Why would you suppress the xsi result prefix?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: If you do not include the prefix "xsi" in the list of values for the "exclude-result-prefixes" attribute, every literal result element will be output as having this namespace node. This is the sole purpose of the e.r.p attr. Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use:-

```
<exercises xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd">
```

Directly in your XSL, that would work, you only really need xsl:element if can't hard code the tag name.  Similarly with attributes you can add them directly unless you need to make conditional.